# How can I find the content type of the file when user uploads it using java servlets?

Tags: java, file, file-upload

Whenever a user uploads a file I need to know the file's content type using java servlets.

Answer (score 1):

When you get a file from an upload, get its type via http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html .